# ADL default merge copy activity

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I am using the "MergeFile" in default copy activity. My source is azure blob storage and my destination is ADL Store. However, I get the following error.

> ErrorCode=UserErrorFileNotFound,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Cannot
>   find the 'Azure Data Lake Store' file.
>   ,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=The
>   remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.,Source=System,'.

How do I specify the file name for output to resolve this error?
I am following this documentation page for default copy activity. 
[blob connector](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-azure-blob-connector/).

I have also tried with using a specific file name at output dataset.

**Update:**
If I change the destination to azure blob then i do not get that error but another error related to xml which I believe is a user error.

> Copy activity encountered a user error:
>   ErrorCode=UserErrorSourceDataContainsMoreColumnsThanDefined,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Error
>   found when processing 'Csv/Tsv Format Text' source
>   '01/1001464881_1001464795_2015-01-01_1.13.05.152__1000.xml' with row
>   number 1: found more columns than expected column count:
>   1.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,'.

My goal is to merge xml files from directory and sub-directory into single big file.